# Include a php file from another plugin

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development

Inside one of small custom plugins I really need to inlcude a file from another plugin, in order to be able to create and save obhect of a class that is declared there.

What I have tried and the closest is this:

```
include_once($plugin_url.'plugin-name/classes/event.php');
```

The error I get in the debug logs is the following:

```
PHP Warning:  include_once(http://.../plugin-name/classes/event.php): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in ..
```

I wonder what would be the correct way to reuse the logic of that class to only be able to create and save objects.

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: $plugins_url is going use an absolute path which leads to a security problem on your server. Have you tried `plugin_basename` to grab a variable and try a relative path ? https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_basename

Answer (score 2):

Including a PHP file requires to provide its exact file path, not the URL.

Try this instead:

```
include_once( WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/plugin-name/classes/event.php' );
```

Hope it helps.